# Transaction not supported

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, transactions, stellar-sdk, accounts

I configured a private Stellar blockchain network composed of 2 nodes. When I try to create an account on this private blockchain I get the following error:

```json
stellar_sdk.exceptions.BadRequestError: {
  "type": "https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/transaction_failed",
  "title": "Transaction Failed",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "The transaction failed when submitted to the stellar network. The `extras.result_codes` field on this response contains further details.  Descriptions of each code can be found at: https://developers.stellar.org/api/errors/http-status-codes/horizon-specific/transaction-failed/",
  "extras": {
    "envelope_xdr": "AAAAAgAAAABpI82a6KV/xCASiYFYlwqNNWVnT4z9bQZcSe0GOXLhdAAAAGQAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABiLw9kAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADnFYBw9mc43/h4oICQO3djebdhvk/0/F107S67CTL4WwAAAAAHTTOgAAAAAAAAAAE5cuF0AAAAQIU9vvHnLu1b+xeB61qpAFZlwqoNvORaisN7gp8rAYBGT84NewdPwBbHpTAzI0Gphum2ues4GPDh5UxVbK506Qg=",
    "result_codes": {
      "transaction": "tx_not_supported"
    },
    "result_xdr": "AAAAAAAAAGT////0AAAAAA=="
  }
```

I'm unable to figure out which is the problem.
To create an account I used the following python program:

```python
from stellar_sdk import Keypair, Network, Server, TransactionBuilder

server = Server(horizon_url="http://192.168.184.62:8000")

#### destination address
destination = Keypair.random()
print(destination.secret)
print(destination.public_key)

#### root secret
source = Keypair.from_secret("SBZ2E3NQE4ZEN3GAR2WZNYKYEXB37CZXPZYO7WKPQ2KPSLYNVB6VNI5B")

source_account = server.load_account(account_id=source.public_key)
transaction = (
    TransactionBuilder(
        source_account=source_account,
        network_passphrase="Private Network ; February 2022",
        base_fee=100,
    )
    .append_create_account_op(
        destination=destination.public_key, starting_balance="12.25"
    )
    .set_timeout(30)
    .build()
)
transaction.sign(source)
response = server.submit_transaction(transaction)
print(f"Transaction hash: {response['hash']}")
print(
    f"New Keypair: \n\taccount id: {destination.public_key}\n\tsecret seed: {destination.secret}"
)
```

The 2 stellar core instances are configured like the following one of the first node:

```
# What port stellar-core listens for commands on. This is for Horizon server.
HTTP_PORT=11626
PUBLIC_HTTP_PORT=true

# If it is true, It prevents you from trying to connect to other peers
RUN_STANDALONE=false

NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="Private Network ; February 2022"
NODE_SEED="SCDV7D5P7B7N3WDXR73ATFAH7PXFQ2BKWLHAPP67Z2XPU5X33URJYO22 self"

# Only nodes that want to participate in SCP should set NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true.
# Most instances should operate in observer mode with NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=false.
NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true

# Postgres DB URL
DATABASE="postgresql://dbname=core host=core_database user=stellar password=stellar"

# The port other instances of stellar-core can connect to you on.
PEER_PORT=11625

KNOWN_CURSORS=["HORIZON"]

# Log level setup
# COMMANDS=["ll?level=trace"]

FAILURE_SAFETY=0
UNSAFE_QUORUM=true

NODE_HOME_DOMAIN="home"

# Stellar Testnet validators
[[HOME_DOMAINS]]
HOME_DOMAIN="home"
QUALITY="LOW"

[[VALIDATORS]]
NAME="node2"
HOME_DOMAIN="home"
PUBLIC_KEY="GDU3UY5QCEWQENXW4S7QXWMG3TU36BCMWAOLUIRGXIB3FKDFHGU2N5PA"
ADDRESS="192.168.1.172"
HISTORY="curl -sf 192.168.1.172:2000/{0} -o {1}"


[HISTORY.local]
get="cp /archive/{0} {1}"
put="cp {0} /archive/{1}"
mkdir="mkdir -p /archive/{0}"

[HISTORY.history_node2]
get='curl -sf 192.168.1.172:2000/{0} -o {1}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone that will have the same problem, I finally was able to figure out the solution. By looking at the stellar-core http info page at `http://192.168.184.62:11626/info` I found that the `info.ledger.version` parameter was equal to `0`. To solve the problem I manually upgraded the network to the protocol version 18 as described in the [official documentation](https://developers.stellar.org/docs/run-core-node/network-upgrades/):

```bash
stellar-core http-command 'upgrades?mode=set&upgradetime=1970-01-01T00:00:00Z&protocolversion=18&basereserve=5000000'
```

To solve this problem at node creation time you can use the `COMMANDS` option in `stellare-core.cfg`:

```bash
COMMANDS=["ll?level=info", "upgrades?mode=set&upgradetime=1970-01-01T00:00:00Z&protocolversion=18&basereserve=5000000"]
```